# How to change the order of object( not array ) in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one set of object(key value pair )

```
var data  = {
         "AnomalyEnableLatch": "false",
        "DistLogPeriod": "0",
        "AedCooldown": "0",
        "AedEnableLatch": "false",
        "AedGuardBand": "0",
        "AedSensitivity": "0",
        "AedWindowSize": "0",
        "AnomalyCurrentNoiseFloor": "10",
        "AnomalyGuardBandSize": "32",
        "AnomalyKsigToStart": "40",
        "AnomalyMinSnrToStop": "100",
        "AnomalyWindowSize": "651"
    };
```

This list will be dynamic one.

I need to order by two params

one is starts with **aed** and another set starts with **anomaly**.

Actually, i am getting correct order from api response. While working on js, order changing automatically by asc.

It should not do like this. I need to do work on actual order.

Otherwise i need to change the order. I need a order as given in above set

http://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/ADukg/11659/

Comment: You **cannot** order keys of object. But you can order the way you access them. Try `keys = Object.keys(obj); keys.sort(...your logic to sort...)` and not access it

Comment: are you asking for an array of objects [{},{},{}]? or an array of arrays [[],[],[]]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the order is not changing. But the console will show like that.

Just observe `console.log(Object.keys(data))` before using filter. It's just un ordered array of object properties. Now, if you want to sort alphabetically, then

you could do is use Object.keys(), and sort the Array, then iterate it through object.

```
Object.keys(data)
      .sort() // sort keys alphabetically
      .forEach(function(v, i) {
          console.log(v, data[v]); // access properties(keys) alphabetically
       });
```

Comment: Just FYI, people over 10k can see deleted answer and its not good to delete a downvoted answer and then adding another one. Instead, update the same answer with the given feedback.

Comment: I thought the same but even I have to delete one to update another now.

Comment: That was a general feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you cannot sort/order keys in object. But you can order the way you access the keys.

You can use following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ADukg/11661/) to debug or following SO snippet.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';

  $scope.data = {
    "AnomalyEnableLatch": "false",
    "DistLogPeriod": "0",
    "AedCooldown": "0",
    "AedEnableLatch": "false",
    "AedGuardBand": "0",
    "AedSensitivity": "0",
    "AedWindowSize": "0",
    "AnomalyCurrentNoiseFloor": "10",
    "AnomalyGuardBandSize": "32",
    "AnomalyKsigToStart": "40",
    "AnomalyMinSnrToStop": "100",
    "AnomalyWindowSize": "651"
  };

  $scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.data);

  $scope.keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return getDifference(a, b, "Aed") || getDifference(a, b, "Anomal") || a.localeCompare(b)
  });

  function getDifference(a, b, s) {
    return b.startsWith(s) - a.startsWith(s)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="k in keys">
          {{k}} : {{ data[k] }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of keys in a JavaScript object is not guaranteed. There are two possible ways to approach this:

1. **The keys and their order are known before:** In this case, predefine your array of keys and use `Array.prototype.map` to build an ordered array from your data map.
2. **If the keys are dynamic too,** use `Object.keys` to extract the keys, sort them as needed using `Array.prototype.sort(compareFn)`. Then, you can use this sorted key array as described in method 1

Sample Code for getting an ordered array out of a map given an ordered set of keys:

```
var data = {...}; //Original data map

var orderedKeys = ["firstKey", "secondKey"]; //Array of preordered keys

var sortedArrayOfMaps = orderedKeys.map(function(key){var o={}; o[key]=data[key]; return o;}) //Use map to get ordered array of objects
```

I have also updated the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzgh4xjr/2/) using this method for your reference